# puppet fileserver serve non-module file

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

I'd like to server file which is located in `/etc/puppet/files/key.pgp`

```
  file { "/var/www/key.gpg":
    ensure  => present,
    source  => 'puppet:///files/key.gpg',
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/key.gpg
```

auth.conf: (I understood that this should match `file*`)

```
path /file
allow *
```

fileserver.conf:

```
[files]
  path /etc/puppet/files
  allow *
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using librarian for managing my modules, so I don't wanna put anything configuration specific to modules dir.

Answer (score 1):

The file description should have the full path contained:

```
file { '/etc/puppet/files/gpg.key'
...
```

Check if files on server are accessible by the user that runs the puppet master. Also check if puppet is allowed to descend into the specified directory. If it is a gpg.key file, there is a very high chance that access mode is 0600 and puppet is not allowed to access it (maybe owned by root or somebody else).

Comment: I had there full path, the problem is somewhere else. Permissions are correct, when I tried to specify source as: `puppet:////etc/puppet/files/key.gpg` it works on the local machnine, but it's not very useful for the others. The problem is with mountpoints other than `modules`

Answer (score 0):

This configuration looks correct, *provided* your Puppet agent is running on a host in the 192.168.1.x subnet.

The deny is coming from `fileserver.conf`, since your `auth.conf` is allowing all the `/file*` resources.  It would seem that your puppet agent is not connecting form an IP in this range -- try adding `allow *` to the `fileserver.conf` [files] section temporarily to confirm this.

If your puppet agent host is multihomed, check which interface it is sending from.

Also check the permissions and ownership on the fileserver.conf is correct.

Comment: Even if I use `allow *` it doesn't work. When I have the file in `/etc/puppet/modules/reprepro/files/key.pgp` it is served. However when moved to `/etc/puppet/files/reprepro/files/key.pgp` it suddenly doesn't work, even though I've changed the mountpoint to `files`